# Subversion/Git ignore settings for any language/IDE

Tags: version-control

I ran into the issue that when I start a new project in a new language or a new IDE I never know what to put in my Git-ignore file (or subversion ignore, they should ignore the same files either way)  So I figured I should ask the always knowledgeable SO.

For example: for C# With Visual Studio I ignore:
/bin
/obj
*.user
*.suo

note: Specifically I am wondering about VHDL with Quartus 10.1 however I would love to see a nice list going here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/github/gitignore for some example configurations.